# Security class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to use the Security class in Codeigniter 2.0.2 but I cant seem to find the class to load. Is it hidden somewhere?

Security Library as shown in CI user guide:

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html
```

Tried searching     /system/libraries but it is not there...

Trying to load the security class with      $this->load->library('security');  gives me an error:

```
Unable to load the requested class: security
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is in helper according to [codeigniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html)

try

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Comment: does anyone know why it is listed as a class in the user guide then?