# Enabling REST on HMVC CodeIgniter setup

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, hmvc

I have just finished setting up an HMVC CodeIgniter following the steps [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc).

I am now trying to create a module "api" which I wish to use [Phil Sturgeon's REST library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/).

It states [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430118/codeigniter-hmvc-rest) that I need to extend the MX_Controller rather than the CI_Controller and I did.

My initial setup was like this

```
application
--modules
----api
------config
------controller
------libraries
```

I kept getting an error with loading Rest_Controller so I have tried moving the REST_Controller and Format libraries to application/libraries that seemed to fix the loading issue but now i am getting the error below whenever i try to access it via http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/api/example/user/id/1/format/json

"An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: security"

I am expecting for the output to be "{"id":1,"name":"Some Guy","email":"example1@example.com","fact":"Loves swimming"}"

What am I missing? Would it be possible to keep the REST_Controller and Format libraries under the api module? If so, how?

Comment: can i ask where can i see how to set up rest in hmvc?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268884/security-class-in-codeigniter)

Open Rest_Controller.php go to line 173 and change the following code

```
$this->load->library('security');
```

to

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

EDIT:

To have the REST_Controller and Format libraries under the api module.

Move the REST_Controller to api/controllers/REST_Controller.php and Format to api/libraries/Format.php